# How to clear bash/Linux history completely and permanently?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, unix

I want to clear all previous commands from the history of my server. I used **history -c** and it seems all things are cleared but when I ssh to the server again, all the commands are still there and they are not deleted.

How can I clear them permanently? Answers are welcome.

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow is only for questions that are about **writing software**. This should instead be on [unix.se] or [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: This should be migrated to the U&L main site, not the Meta site...

Answer (score 2):

There is the .bash_history file that is differente from history command
Use:

```
 cd ~
 rm .bash_history
```

see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029850/why-is-history-and-bash-history-different-and-how-to-delete-an-entry-in-history

Comment: Thank you, its working well. But deleting bash directory is not recommended because it will be recreated again and again.

Comment: Yes! In this case, use  "unset HISTFILE".  If HISTFILE is unset, or if the history file is unwritable, the history is never saved

Comment: Sounds good, but here approach should be to delete the history permanently for once or only on demand  using command line. Thank you anyway.

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section *Answer Well-Asked Questions*, and therein the bullet point regarding questions that "are not about software development, as defined in the Help Center".

Comment: This does exactly that (albeit clumsily, `cd` is almost never particularly necessary).